# Как загрузить много строк в таблицу БД?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, sql-server

Есть задача, загрузить в таблицу миллион строк, фейковых данных.

Интересует следующий вопрос, какие могут быть подходы к данной задаче, в общем, без привязки к типу базы данных?

Например, одна умеет получать на вход CSV файл, другая нет, но сам подход существует, можно написать процедуру, можно bash скрипт.

Подскажите, кто какой путь знает.

Comment: почему именно фейковые данные? Проводите какие-то тесты?

Answer (score 5):

Хороший вопрос! К сожалению, я не знаю элегантного и простого ответа на этот вопрос.

По непонятным мне причинам до сих пор не существует единого SQL стандарта для быстрой загрузки данных. Во всяком случае я такой стандарт [найти не смог](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+standard+(ansi%7Ciso)+bulk+(load%7Cinsert)&pws=0&gl=us&gws_rd=cr#pws=0&gl=us&q=%2B%22sql+standard%22+(ansi%7Ciso)+bulk+(load%7Cinsert)).

Практически все серьезные RDBMS (СУБД) системы имеют свой (несовместимый с другими) способ для быстрой загрузки данных (смотрите ссылки ниже).

Можно попробовать написать "адаптер" для каждой СУБД, использующий *"bulk load / insert"* решение данной СУБД. Т.е создать адаптеры для каждой СУБД, которую вы хотите поддерживать в своем приложении или использовать универсальный и наивный (медленный) подход вставки по одной строке...

Известные мне инструменты для быстрой загрузки данных для нескольких популярных СУБД:

**Oracle:**

[External Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/et_concepts.htm#g1017623) - используя внешние таблицы, можно просто вставлять данные в другую таблицу (используя [direct-path insert](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9014.htm#SQLRF01604)):

```
 insert /*+append*/ into target_table select * from source_external_table;
```

PS `Direct-path INSERT` "откатится" к обычному `conventional INSERT` если хотя бы одно условие (см. ссылку выше) не будет выполнено

Данное решение работает достаточно быстро и позоляет "распараллелить" задачу по нескольким узлам кластера (Real Application Cluster), если секционировать данные и распределить файлы на разных узлах кластера.

[PL/SQL Bulk Collect](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/tuning.htm#LNPLS891) ([Пример использования](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-sep/o52plsql-1709862.html))

[SQL Loader](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-DD843EE2-1FAB-4E72-A115-21D97A501ECC.htm#SUTIL003)

**SQL Server:**

[Bulk Copy Program utility AKA BCP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx)

[Bulk Insert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx)

**MySQL:**

[LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)

[Bulk Data Loading for InnoDB Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html)

**PostgreSQL:**

[COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html)

PS [@root_xPovierennyy напомнил об очень важном аспекте - индексах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/602114/%d0%94%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%83-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b/602166?noredirect=1#comment816775_602166):

**Если у вас есть такая возможность и если это целесообразно** то сделайте следующее для ускорения загрузки:

- удалите все индексы целевой таблицы
- удалите все "referential constraints", связанные с целевой таблицей
- удалите все тригеры целевой таблицы
- пересоздайте, если это необходимо, удаленные объекты.
- Не забудьте пересобрать статистику для целевой таблицы, особенно если значительная часть данных была изменена.

В любом случае надо протестировать и выбрать наиболее подходящее именно для вас решение.

Comment: а как это "быстро"? Ведь без insert вставить данные никак нельзя (или можно?). Можно "переделать" входные данные в формат  таблицы бд, но это (переваривание, конвертирование) тоже занимает время (и нужно самому писать конвертер(?)). Можно временно удалаить индексы, а после вставки снова создать их - так чуток быстрее. Ссылки в вашем ответе не смотрел. но позже обязательно гляну, потому что самому придется загружать миллионы записей в тбл мскл.

Comment: @root_xPovierennyy,  `insert` - `insert'у` рознь ;-). Например в Oracle есть `conventional insert` и `direct-path insert`, который работает быстрее (но у него есть ряд ограничений). Обычно `(перевариванием, конвертированием)` занимаются утилиты для быстрой загрузки. По поводу индексов - __очень хорошее замечание__! Если есть возможность удалить индексы перед загрузкой данных, а потом их пересоздать после загрузки - это будет гораздо эффективнее. Для загрузки миллионов записей в таблицы MS SQL советую воспользоваться `BCP` или `Bulk insert`

Comment: начинаю расти и копить опыт %;) допишите пару слов об индексах в ответ. Хотя вы уже выделили жирненьким -  кто читает и думает - увидит это.

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идёт именно о более-менее общем способе загрузить данные без оглядки на скорость этого процесса, то, как мне кажется, надо посмотреть в сторону XML, этот формат понимают (с той или иной степенью вменяемости этого понимания - но с плоскими файлами проблем именно понимания нет) все популярные СУБД. А генерить фэйк в общем всё равно в каком формате, XML тут ничем не хуже многих прочих, тем более что во избежание проблем, связанных с пониманием структур и схем разными СУБД, желательно готовить фэйк в простейшем формате (одна таблица - один XML для загрузки).

Правда, и тут попадаются свои заморочки, совсем разного масштаба, от забавных казусов и вплоть до нерешаемых проблем. К последним, например, можно отнести проблему загрузки сверхбольших XML-файлов в MySQL (исчерпание памяти и снятие загружающего процесса - хорошо хоть при этом сервер не падает).

Answer (score 0):

Возьмите любой язык программирования, коннектор к базе для этого языка, напишите код:

```
# псевдокод
база = коннектор.создать_соединение(адрес@имябазы)
курсор = база.создать_курсор()

количество_фейков = 1000000
размер_пачки = 10000
х = 0
цикл пока х < количество_фейков {
    пачка = пустой_список
    у = 0
    цикл пока у < размер_пачки {
        пачка.добавить(сгенерировать_фейковую_строку())
        у = у + 1
    }
    курсор.добавить(пачка)
    курсор.сделать_коммит()
    х = х + 1
}

курсор.закрыть_курсор()
база.закрыть_соединение()
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но это всего лишь один из вариантов, и он очень достаточно долгий, суть вопроса больше к вариантам, что бы испробовать и знать как можно больше. Сейчас так и делаю, но из-за того что долго ждать, задумался над другими вариантами.